# How to make MATLAB's xlim auto yet symmetric around 0?

Tags: matlab, plot

I am making a very simple scatter plot.

```
pts = [1 1; -2 1];
scatter(pts(:, 1), pts(:, 2));
```

As we see, the `xlim` is automatically determined by MATLAB to be from `-2` to `1`, which is satisfactory to me.

What annoys me is that the origin `0` is not centered. That is the x-axis is asymmetric around `0`. In this particular example, I want the x-axis to be from `-2` to `2`.

I can surely find the largest absolute value, which is `2` in this case, and manually do `xlim([-2 2])`. Is there a more elegant way, like `axis center` in my imagination?

Comment: I don't think there is an `axis center` option, finding the largest abs value and setting it using `xlim` might be the better method here - since any functions or options will be doing similar things.

Comment: You said manually, that's not far from `xlim([-max(abs(x)),max(abs(x))])` (or in your case `max(abs(pts(:,1)))`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do this, the 1st is by far the easiest to understand...

**Set up your own scatter function (untested):**

```
function h = yourScatter ( varargin )
  h = scatter ( varargin{:} );
  xlim(max(abs(h.Parent.XLim)).*[-1 1])
end
```

*The 2nd line is the same as in @Daniel answer.*

Then you use:

```
pts = [1 1; -2 1];
yourScatter(pts(:, 1), pts(:, 2));
```

**Utilising undocumented listeners**

The more complex and fully automated method you perform using some undocumented listeners.

1st we create a function which we use to create the axes (This function has a listener which calls the sub function where the actual limits are set post you added data):

```
function ax = setupAutoXAxis
  ax = axes ( 'nextplot', 'add' );
  addlistener ( ax, 'MarkedClean', @updateAx );
end
function updateAx ( ax, event )
  % check that any children have been added
  if ~isempty ( ax.Children )
    % extract out all children XData
    currentLim = max(abs([ax.Children.XData]));
    % Check to see if it needs to be updated.
    if ~isempty ( currentLim ) && ~isequal ( ax.XLim, [-currentLim currentLim] )
      ax.XLim = [-currentLim currentLim];
    end
  end
end
```

You then use this like so:

```
ax = setupAutoXAxis()
pts = [1 1; -2 1];
scatter ( ax, pts(:,1), pts(:,2) );
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work for adding more plots - thats because by setting the limits manually the MarkedClean event isn't triggered (which I was surprised by).  I've had a look and the best fix I can get is to add another listener which results in the MarkedClean event being triggered (The ChildAdded event is triggered before the actual child data is added so we cant use that).

```
function ax = setupAutoXAxis
  ax = axes ( 'nextplot', 'add' );
  addlistener ( ax, 'ChildAdded', @(a,b)set(ax,'XLimMode','auto') );
  addlistener ( ax, 'MarkedClean', @updateAx );
end
function updateAx ( ax, event )
  % check that any children have been added
  if ~isempty ( ax.Children )
    % extract out all children XData
    currentLim = max(abs([ax.Children.XData]));
    % Check to see if it needs to be updated.
    if ~isempty ( currentLim ) && ~isequal ( ax.XLim, [-currentLim currentLim] )
      ax.XLim = [-currentLim currentLim];
    end
  end
end

ax = setupAutoXAxis()
pts = [1 1; -2 1];
scatter ( ax, pts(:,1), pts(:,2) );
scatter ( ax, pts(:,1)+3, pts(:,2) );
```

For info this was tested on R2015a.

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge there is no automatism. You have to do it manually. For an individual axis you can use:

```
xlim(max(abs(xlim)).*[-1 1])
```

For a single line of code which does it for all (2 or 3) axis use:

```
axis(reshape([-1;1]*max(reshape(abs(axis),2,[])),1,[]))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the functionality of axis auto where it picks "nice" endpoints for the axis limits, you can use this:

```
plot([0:1:10], [0:2:20], '-k');   % example plot
axis auto;                        % not strictly necessary
limits = max( abs(gca().YLim) );  % take the larger of the two "nice" endpoints
ylim( [-limits, limits] );        % use this nice value for both endpoints
```